# Logging of data change in mysql tables using ado.net

Tags: mysql, logging, ado.net

Is there any work around to get the latest change in MySQL Database using Ado.NET.
i.e. change in which table, which column, performed operation, old and new value. both for single table change and multiple table change. want to log the changes in my own new table.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways how change tracking can be implemented for mysql:

- triggers: you can add DB trigger for insert/update/delete that creates an entry in the audit log.
- add application logic to track changes. Implementation highly depends on your data layer; if you use ADO.NET DataAdapter, RowUpdating event is suitable for this purpose.

Also you have the following alternatives how to store audit log in mysql database:

- use one table for audit log with columns like: id, table, operation, new_value (string), old_value (string). This approach has several drawbacks: this table will grow up very fast (as it holds history for changes in all tables), it keeps values as strings, it saves excessive data duplicated between old-new pairs, changeset calculation takes some resources on every insert/update.
- use 'mirror' table (say, with '_log' suffix) for each table with enabled change tracking. On insert/update you can execute additional insert command into mirror table - as result you'll have record 'snapshots' on every save, and by this snapshots it is possible to calculate what and when is changed. Performance overhead on insert/update is minimal, and you don't need to determine which values are actually changed - but in 'mirror' table you'll have a lot of redundant data as full row copy is saved even if only one column is changed.
- hybrid solution when record 'snapshots' are temporarily saved, and then processed in background to store differences in optimal way without affecting app performance.

There are no one best solution for all cases, everything depends on the concrete application requirements: how many inserts/updates are performed, how audit log is used etc.